# How to Create simple View or query subdocument

Tags: couchbase

I read the docs - but can't seem to get my head around this ( I'm a SQL guy )

1) I loaded a json file in using CBdocloader

```
[
  {
    "ID": "9e78f4a6-4061-48aa-8154-0b738d93461b",
    "More fields": ""
  }
]
```

2) There is now an object in my bucket calles values100 ( that was the name of the file ) .

3) How to I access the data in this object in the bucket that I imported through a query or view?

Select * from mybucket returns 1 result that has all the rows I loaded - but I really want to query that data in that bucket?  Should I create a view? Should I query a View?  My Question is #3 but I am confused..

Comment: I have revised the question - I hope it makes sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there are a couple of things going on:

a. [cbdocloader](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/CLI/cbdocloader_tool.html) expects that each document is contained in a separate file.  The behavior desired indicates that each document should instead be its own file, rather than one single document on Couchbase. The tool will then create multiple couchbase documents which can be indexed.  I'm not sure there is a way to split out the text file using the tool; you may have to write a script to do it for you.

b. Couchbase is intended to be a document database, not a SQL database. As such, the way you would access a document in a majority of the cases is via the document id, which should have some significance to your application. This is not to say you can't look up the document id in an index, but you may find a SQL database to work better if you plan to do a lot of complex queries.  If you need help on creating an index, please post a new question.

Comment: ok thanks - I thought I was missing something. That makes more sense.